# memory game in java point declaration

Tags: java, return, compare

So currently I  have an assignment for class to make a memory game. The "cards" work as I want to. Now what i have to do is have the point system in place. I made 36 buttons in a JFrame now what I need to do is export an int to my method **check** (see my code) and compare them. But if I want to do this I need to be able to assign the number that's on the card to some int and i do not know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

so far this is my code.

```
    public class Bord extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static Integer[] getallen = new Integer[]{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18};


public static int speler1; 
public static int speler2; 
public static int setjes; 
public static boolean beurt; 
public static int x; 
public static int y; 

public static Integer[] generator()
{    
   //shuffled de getallen array 
      List<Integer> List2 = Arrays.asList(getallen); 

   Collections.shuffle(List2); 

   return getallen; 

}
```

after this comes a big list of buttons and what happens if they get clicked. I'll list two for example

```
 private void BtnEenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     BtnEen.setText(""+getallen[1]);

 }                                      

private void BtnTweeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   BtnTwee.setText(""+getallen[2]);
```

So now I need to make a method check that compares the two cards to each other and gives a point to the right player if the cards are the same. So far i made this

```
public static int check(int x, int y)
{
    while(beurt == false){
      if(x == y)
      {

      }  
    }

    return setjes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't do this already you need to store wich player turned the 'cards', then you could store the values assigned to your cards in a global variable, compare them and perform any action you want depending on the result of your comparison:

```
private int valueOne =0, valueTwo =0;
```

and in your action performed methods:

```
 private void BtnEenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     BtnEen.setText(""+getallen[1]);
     valueOne = getallen[1];
 }
```

and so on.
Then you can simply compare both values in your `check()`-function

Comment: I was thinking in this direction. I stored who was turning the cards in a boolean so player2 is false and player 1 is true. But if i do the valueOne you were talking about. Won't this give an error message because ValueOne will already be assigned after the first attempt?

Comment: What sets `valueTwo`.  And what causes  `valueOne` and `valueTwo` to be compared once both have been set?

Comment: You could for example define a function (for example `setOpenCardValues(int toSet)`, that determines whether `valueOne` is already set and then sets `valueOne` or `valueTwo` depending on whether `valueOne` is already set. After the comparison you simply set both values back to zero. You could even call your `check()` function from within the `setOpenCardValues`function when valueTwo has been set, then you automatically compare the values after the second card has been turned.